# Where should I put the login logic? DispatcherServlet or a Filter?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, authentication, front-controller

The following 2 things both implement the `front controller pattern`:

1. `DispatcherServlet` defined by Spring
2. `Filter` defined by servlet spec

I think login logic should be placed in the `front controller`. But which one should I use in a Spring MVC web application?

Comment: should be interceptor.

Comment: "I think login logic should be placed in the front controller". Well Spring Security has authentication logic in filters, for instance [`BasicAuthenticationFilter`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/www/BasicAuthenticationFilter.html). Also look at Spring Security filter chain as a whole. But if you need to implement login logic, I would recomment to use what Spring security already offers and don't try to come up with your own authentication mechanisms if you can avoid it.

Comment: What do you mean by "login logic"? - account enable disabling, or password verification, or .... ?

Comment: @Ralph User must input username/password to authenticate himself before he can access other parts of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of implementing that by your own, I strongly recommend to use [Spring-Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/).

BTW: The way Spring-Security hooks into the HTTP-Request handling process (the "entry"-point), is based on a Servlet filter ([`org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/DelegatingFilterProxy.html)).